# Highcharts: Align multiple charts in same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

Following this demo here (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types) I am trying to have a Pie chart and a bar chart on the same page.

The catch is I would like the Pie chart to be large on the left and then the bar chart on the right. I see the code to move the pie chart around, but I cannot figure out how to do the same with the bar chart, as it seems to want to span the entire container width.  I understand that I could have two independent charts and place them in their own floating DIVs, but since the combining of charts is possible, I thought this would be a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [chart.marginLeft](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft) to half of the chart width. And set [pie.center](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.size) x coordinate to a negative value.

```
chart: {
   marginLeft: 400
},

series: [{
   center: ['-75%', '50%'],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L55w9n53/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!